# Chart.js throwing an error when funciton used to populate data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I am using Chart.js and react-chartjs-2 to add charts to my React application.

I am trying to load data into a chart as follows:

```
<Chart type="line" data={this.getData}/>
```

`getData` is a simple function which converts the data in the component's props into a format Chart.js understands:

```
function getData() {
    const data = this.props.data;
    [...]
    return {
        labels: dates // This is an array of dates as strings, ex ["2022-11-14", ...]
        datasets: [{ label: "Some Label", data: sales}] // sales is an array of numbers
    }
}
```

However, when I load the Chart I get the following error:

```
TypeError: t is undefined
```

This error goes away if I hardcode the data into the component, ie:

```
<Chart type="line" data={{
    labels: ["one", "two", "three"]
    datasets: [{ label: "Some Label", data: [1,2,3]}]
}}/>
```

So despite the fact that `getData()` returns data in the exact same way that it's hardcoded, that error is thrown if I use getData() instead of hardcoding the chart data.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling a function inside the `data` so add the missing parenthesis

```
<Chart type="line" data={this.getData()}/>
```